How do you solve the analogy 369 : 329 : : 237 :?
This question was asked in IMO (International Mathematics Olympiad) conducted by SOF (Science Olympiad Foundation) in the logic section, it was the first question itself, here is the link to the paper:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Np2PQXWvqQI
I came across the following analogy and I’m having trouble identifying the pattern:
369 : 329 :: 237 : ?
I’ve noticed that the numbers on the left and right side of the colon appear to be related, and I need help figuring out the logic or pattern that connects them.
What I've tried:

I first checked the difference between 369 and 329, which is 40. So I thought of subtracting 40 from 237, but that gives me 197, which isn't one of the answer options.
I also considered squaring the digits of the numbers, but I'm not sure how to apply that to find the correct answer.

The options for the missing number are:

169
196
149
100

Could someone please explain how to solve this analogy and help me understand the pattern behind it?

Are the double colons between 329 and 237 part of the puzzle or a typo ? (in general, I find puzzles asking to identify a pattern from a series of only three numbers quite poor, with many different answers being equally logical)

I think the design of this puzzle (please confirm @randomuser) is something to the effect of: "369 is to (:) 329 as (::) 237 is to (:) ???".

@ConnieMnemonic Exactly

Is this a part of a series of questions? If so could you maybe share some more in the comments so we can get an idea of the difficulty? I.e. if the similar questions have connections like “add 35” or “multiply by 2” then “subtract 40” seems reasonable and there may be a typo. But if the connections are “multiple the first digit by 2, leave the second digit unchanged, and subtract one from the final digit” it’s worth looking at further!

The only common thread I see is that each number listed is the sum of three squares (369 = 169 + 100 + 100, 329 = 324 + 4 + 1, 237 = 196 + 25 + 16), which would make the answer 149 (64 + 49 + 36), but this seems weak to me and it isn't really an analogous connection.

Nope, its not a part of a series of questions. Its a single logic question which was asked in the IMO(International Mathematics Olympiad) paper conducted by SOF.

The sum of three squares seems plausible, but then again there's not really a connection.  I also noticed that 3 of the options are perfect squares and only 149 isn't but that's more of strategic guessing honestly.

@randomuser if you edit the attribution into the question, it could be reopened.

@ilikecorgis The solution you gave was the solution posted by the channel that was linked by the original poster: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GBVUnbyu5ng

In case anyone is confused: the "International Mathematics Olympiad" mentioned here is neither international nor an olympiad in any useful sense, and has nothing to do with the famous International Mathematical Olympiad that takes place every year. The "Science Olympiad Foundation" is a for-profit company that runs school competitions in India and gives them pretentious names.

There can be a lot of complex relationships that satisfy such an open pattern question but judging based on the choice of these specific numbers and how this appeared in a class 10 IMO, I feel like this question is linked to the number of factors.
For the first pair of numbers:

369 = 3*3*41 (number of factors = 3)
329 = 7*47 (number of factors = 2)
The number of factors is reduced by 1 in the second number.

Now for the second pair of numbers:

237 = 3*79 (number of factors = 2)

So the second number in this pair should have just 1 factor, i.e. it must be a prime number. The only prime option here is 149.
Here's another way that leads to the same answer:

If we sum up all the digits of the first number and then add 5 to the square of the sum, we get the second number in the pair => 3+6+9 = 18; 18*18 = 324; 324+5 = 329
Similarly, for 237, we get 2+3+7 = 12; 12*12 = 144; 144+5 = 149

